# itemToDto does not existin current context

Tags: asp.net, api, dto

Im following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

On how to create an API with ASP.NET and at some point(Prevent-Overpostinh is the corresponding Headline) i seem to miss some sort of Dependency.

Im getting the Error:
"The name 'ItemToDTO' does not exist in the current context"

```
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EventItemDTO>>> GetEventItems()
        {
            return await _context.EventItems
            .Select(x => ItemToDTO(x))
            .ToListAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the function so it can be called

```cs
    private static TodoItemDTO ItemToDTO(TodoItem todoItem) =>
        new TodoItemDTO
        {
            Id = todoItem.Id,
            Name = todoItem.Name,
            IsComplete = todoItem.IsComplete
        };
```

Edit;

This is a more concise way of writing:

```cs
private static TodoItemDTO ItemToDTO(TodoItem todoItem)
{
    return new TodoItemDTO
    {
        Id = todoItem.Id,
        Name = todoItem.Name,
        IsComplete = todoItem.IsComplete
    };
}
```

You could also do this without a function call:

```cs
_context.EventItems
    .Select(x => new TodoItemDTO
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            IsComplete = x.IsComplete
        })
```

Comment: @NickyB0T no probs. See if it works better now, and then please accept this answer so we know you've been helped.

Comment: i need to wait 10 more mins for that

Comment: Would it be conceptual wrong to add a constructor to the DTO object that takes the TodoItem as the argument?

Comment: @sommmen Please can you explain what this code does? I am trying to understand what's the best way to initialize a DTO object. Could this be done in any other way? What's the best way to map a DTO object to the actual model class?

Comment: @Akbar i've updated the answer to be a bit more clear. Generally you can either create a new dto object, then fill the properties with the values from your model. If you have a lot of dto objects, you can look into a mapper like mapster or automapper  https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html these will only work in memory however, so you'd call `ToList` and then use automapper.